# EC2 ephemeral drives missing on 11.10 AMI? (ami-21f53948)

Tags: 11.10, amazon-ec2

Sorry in advance if this is the wrong place for this kind of question.

I'm porting some of my EC2 application's start scripts to the 11.10 `ami-21f53948` AMI, from a similar 9.10 (`ami-6832d801`).

One step of the process is to raid together the 4 ephemeral drives that come with a `c1.xlarge`.  In the the previous AMI these could be found at `/dev/sd[b-e]`.  These devices appear to be absent in the new AMI.

It seems an instance using the new AMI believes they *should* be there:

```
$ curl 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/' && echo
ami
ephemeral0
ephemeral1
ephemeral2
ephemeral3
root
$ curl 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ephemeral0' && echo
sdb
$ curl 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ephemeral1' && echo
sdc
$ curl 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ephemeral2' && echo
sdd
$ curl 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ephemeral3' && echo
sde
```

Does anyone have any light to shed on what I can do here?  Perhaps they are available under different names (despite the block device mapping) or maybe I can create the needed device files?  Any help is appreciated.

While it's not clear exactly how, this [issue report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/690286) may be related.  Much like the goggles, passing the block device mapping arguments to `ec2-start-instances` (as one post suggested) did nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block device mapping is wrong.  The ephemeral drives can be found at `/dev/xvd[b-e]`, following the virtualized block device naming scheme.